# JavaFX: "error: Location is not set"

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I know that this error has been seen several times but after trying all that I can read on it I still get sucked with this error.

So in my JavaFX project I try to load an fxml file but I have this error:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2434)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
        at PeerApp.start(PeerApp.java:25)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
Exception running application PeerApp
```

Here is my code:

```
public class PeerApp extends Application {

    private AnchorPane mainLayout;
    private Stage primaryStage;

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(PeerApp.class.getResource("PeerAppMessenger/resources/fxml/PeerApp.fxml"));
            mainLayout = loader.load();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        this.primaryStage.setTitle("Peer Messenger");
        JFXDecorator decorator = new JFXDecorator(primaryStage, mainLayout);
        decorator.setCustomMaximize(true);
        Scene scene = new Scene(decorator, 600, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

And finally here's my project structure:
[image: Project Structure]

The only way that I get it to work is to put my fxml file in my src folder and then set the path passed to `getResource()` to simply "PeerApp.fxml". It works well when I run with Intellij but not in command line... Any idea  why ?

**EDIT**
I changed the path passed to `getResource()` with `/production/PeerAppMessenger/fxml/PeerApp.fxml` so now it seems that the file is found but I have this error now:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/Users/yoangrandjacques/Documents/Development/Peer/PeerAppMessenger/out/production/PeerAppMessenger/fxml/PeerApp.fxml:9

        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:103)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:922)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:971)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:220)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:744)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
        at PeerApp.start(PeerApp.java:25)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: PeerAppController
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:920)
        ... 14 more
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Children: child node is null: parent = StackPane@17b46e9e[styleClass=jfx-decorator-content-container]
        at javafx.scene.Parent$2.onProposedChange(Parent.java:435)
        at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.add(VetoableListDecorator.java:206)
        at com.jfoenix.controls.JFXDecorator.<init>(JFXDecorator.java:255)
        at com.jfoenix.controls.JFXDecorator.<init>(JFXDecorator.java:92)
        at PeerApp.start(PeerApp.java:32)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
Exception running application PeerApp
```

Comment: I think you need to convert your project to jar file before running it from command line

Comment: @SahilManchanda Really ? At this time I compile with this command line: `javac -cp src:lib/PeerAPI.jar:lib/jfoenix.jar -d out/ src/PeerApp.java` and I run it with this one: `java -classpath out:lib/PeerAPI.jar:lib/jfoenix.jar PeerApp` it has to wok no ? PS: see my edit